# NotifierConfiguration example in 2.1.4 SBA documentation

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am trying to implement RemindingNotifier in my Spring Boot Admin application but code snippet [given in documentation](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.1.4/#reminder-notifications) uses a  "repository" variable which is not declared anywhere. How to get this variable?

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFIs8.png)

```
@Configuration
public class NotifierConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Notifier notifier;

    @Primary
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public RemindingNotifier remindingNotifier() {
        RemindingNotifier notifier = new RemindingNotifier(notifier, repository);
        notifier.setReminderPeriod(Duration.ofMinutes(10)); 
        notifier.setCheckReminderInverval(Duration.ofSeconds(10)); 
        return notifier;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please post your code as text, not an image. Images aren't searchable. Also, people volunteering to answer questions here are busy people, like you. So the easier it is for them to copy, paste and test code in their own environment code, the faster you'll get an answer. :-)

Comment: Hi Ageax, i tried doing that first but website won't let me post the code due to some formatting issue. hence i used the image as a workaround.

Comment: Ah okay. Some of the new handling for questions, take a little getting used to.  I don't know anything about Spring Boot Admin, but it looks like the variable is passed into the constructor. See line # 80 https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/38452e4578f0aa9bfc83d41ebc3d04f98f4b1e7c/spring-boot-admin-samples/spring-boot-admin-sample-reactive/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/SpringBootAdminApplication.java

Answer (score 2):

So i was able to solve this by using this from SBA documentation.

```
    @Configuration
    public static class NotifierConfig {
        private final InstanceRepository repository;
        private final ObjectProvider<List<Notifier>> otherNotifiers;

        public NotifierConfig(InstanceRepository repository, ObjectProvider<List<Notifier>> otherNotifiers) {
            this.repository = repository;
            this.otherNotifiers = otherNotifiers;
        }

        @Bean
        public FilteringNotifier filteringNotifier() { 
            CompositeNotifier delegate = new CompositeNotifier(otherNotifiers.getIfAvailable(Collections::emptyList));
            return new FilteringNotifier(delegate, repository);
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
        public RemindingNotifier remindingNotifier() { 
            RemindingNotifier notifier = new RemindingNotifier(filteringNotifier(), repository);
            notifier.setReminderPeriod(Duration.ofMinutes(10));
            notifier.setCheckReminderInverval(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            return notifier;
        }
    }
```